# Problem: "Cannot convert argument 1 from 'double' to 'char(*)(double)'"

Tags: c++, arguments, integral

I have a problem with the following assignment. The problem is to find the integral of the function. It gives me the error "Cannot convert argument 1 from 'double' to 'char(*)(double)'". I think the problem is in the bottom, where I define the function. And I am not even sure if I should use char for p.

Does anyone know, what the problem is?

```
/*43. Modify program chapter6_11 to estimate the integral of the function
f (x) = 3x − 2x^2.*/

#include <iostream> //Required for cin, cout
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib> //Required for srand(), rand().
#include <cmath> //Required for pow().
using namespace std;

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Program chapter6_11 */
/* */
/* This program finds the real roots of a cubic polynomial */
/* using the Newton-Raphson method. */
double integral(char(p)(double x), double a, double b, double n);

int main(){
    // Declare objects.
    int iterations(0);
    double a1, a2, a3, x, p, dp, tol;
    cout << "Enter coefficients a1, a2, a3 (here -2, 3 and 0)\n";
    cin >> a1 >> a2 >> a3;
    cout << "Enter initial guess for root\n";
    cin >> x;
// Evaluate p at initial guess.
    p =  -2* x * x + 3 * x + 0;
    // Determine tolerance.
    tol = fabs(p);
    while (tol > 0.001 && iterations < 100)
    {
        // Calculate the derivative.
        dp = 2 * -2 * x + 3;
        // Calculate next estimated root.
        x = x - p / dp;
        // Evaluate p at estimated root.
        p = -2 * x * x + 3 * x + 0;
        tol = fabs(p);
        iterations++;
}
if (tol < 0.001)
{
    cout << "Root is " << x << endl;
    cout << iterations << " iterations\n";
    cout << "Integral is" << integral(p, -100000, 100000, 1000);
}
else
cout << "Did not converge after 100 iterations\n";
return 0;
}

double integral(char(p)(double x), double a, double b, double n) {
    double step = (b - a) / n;  // width of each small rectangle
    double area = 0.0;  // signed area
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        area += p(a + (i + 0.5) * step) * step; // sum up each small rectangle
    }
    return area;
}
```

Comment: I think you should ask yourself *what function am I trying to integrate?* The reason that you are having trouble is that your haven't written or chosen a function to integrate. Obviously you cannot integrate a number, that's what the error is telling you.

Comment: Incidentally I would imagine you want `double(p)(double x)`. Using `char` for an area doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The first parameter should be a function pointer, but you are passing a `double`

Comment: `p` is some value right? And you are trying to multiply that value with `(a + (i + 0.5) * step)`, right? If so, you have to use `*` operator like so: `p * (a + (i + 0.5) * step)`. Now in `main` you declared `p` as `double`. So the declaration cannot change and should be `double p` in `integral` function. I see you are somehow trying to mix `p` and `x` in declaration. What about passing both `p` and `x`. Then doing some operation with them (I don't know what `p(x)` means, multiplying again?) and storing them in `p` like so: `p = p * x`.

Comment: I wonder what calculating roots of a polynomial using the Newton-Raphson method has to do with integration.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling integral,

```
cout << "Integral is" << integral(p, -100000, 100000, 1000);
```

Where p is not a pointer to a function returning a char and taking a double

```
char func(double x);
```

maybe you meant to define such at function?